# How to drag a file from Virtual TreeView to Windows Explorer

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I have a TVirtualStringTree, each node represents a file, what I want to do is to allow a user drag a node to the Windows Explorer or Outlook and the target gets a real file. It seems that I need to implement the `OnGetUserClipboardFormats` and `RenderOLEData` event handler? But I don't know where to start...Would you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Drag and Drop Component Suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop) from Anders Melander.
It's free and will give you all the functionality you will need.

Comment: Thank you Holgerwa. I know that package and it's excellent, I was thinking of using the built-in drag and drop support supplied by Virtual treeview, but it seems using a decent drop and drop component can make the things a lot easier, especially the drag and drop components suite has been enhanced a lot since the last version I looked at, especially the Unicode support!

Comment: it seems that the Drag and Drop Component Suite has been improved a lot! few years ago I evaluated it and it lacked some features I need so I bought from Raize software DropMaster (which is excellent also, but it lack of UNICODE feature for Delphi versions earlier than 2009), but now it has been improved a lot and has all features I want, including UNICODE!